# How to join two queries with unequal results (different columns and rows) in PostgreSQL/Postgis

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.5

In my PostgreSQL/PostGIS database, I have two queries with different results.

Query1:

```
With buffer as 
(
    SELECT   gid, 
             (ST_DumpPoints(ST_Buffer(geom,50,3))).geom as geom
    FROM     cp 
    group by gid, geom --cp being point layer with one row
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT   gid, 
             geom 
    FROM     cp        --cp being point layer with only one row
)
SELECT   gid,
         generate_series(1,12) id,
         (ST_Dump(ST_DelaunayTriangles(ST_Collect(geom),0, 0))).geom as geom
FROM     buffer
group by gid
order by gid, id
```

returns three columns (gid, id, geom) with 12 rows. While, query2:

```
With buffer as 
(
    SELECT   gid, 
             (ST_DumpPoints(ST_Buffer(geom,50,3))).geom as geom
    FROM     cp 
    group by gid, geom --cp being the same point layer
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT   gid, 
             geom 
    FROM     cp        -- cp being the same point layer
)
Select distinct geom as pts, 
       gid 
from   buffer
```

returns two columns (pts, gid) with 13 rows. I want to join these two queries on the basis of gid as I want to automate this process for large number of points. As I recall, first query returns 12 segments/rows (triangles/pie-like wedges geometry) around point layer (cp having gid = 1). The second query returns outer vertices (13 points) of these triangles. I need to join these queries most efficiently such that the desired output should yield four columns like:

```
 gid, id, geom, pts
 1    1   xxx   yyy
 1    2   xxx   yyy
 1    3   xxx   yyy
 1    4   xxx   yyy
 1    5   xxx   yyy
 1    6   xxx   yyy
 1    7   xxx   yyy
 1    8   xxx   yyy
 1    9   xxx   yyy
 1    10  xxx   yyy
 1    11  xxx   yyy
 1    12  xxx   yyy
 1    13  NULL  yyy
```

Can anyone help me to join unequal results of above two queries? Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: do you want to join em on `gid`?.. or on true?.. the fact that you have gid=1 on 13 rows and geom=xxx from id=13 is confusing...

Comment: Yes, I want to join them on the basis of 'gid' because in this case I am only using one point layer but I want to automate this process for a large number of points. Secondly, I have added more details. You are right. The last (13th) row should have geom as NULL. Please see the edit and updated desired output. I have gid as 1 because I am only using one point (cp) here.

Comment: you probably want `outer join` then

Comment: That could be the case as long as I get the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try such (I just CTE your statements and outer join them):

```
with a as (
    With buffer as 
    (
        SELECT   gid, 
                 (ST_DumpPoints(ST_Buffer(geom,50,3))).geom as geom
        FROM     cp 
        group by gid, geom --cp being point layer with one row
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT   gid, 
                 geom 
        FROM     cp        --cp being point layer with only one row
    )
    SELECT   gid,
             generate_series(1,12) id,
             (ST_Dump(ST_DelaunayTriangles(ST_Collect(geom),0, 0))).geom as geom
    FROM     buffer
    group by gid
    order by gid, id
)
, b as (

    With buffer as 
    (
        SELECT   gid, 
                 (ST_DumpPoints(ST_Buffer(geom,50,3))).geom as geom
        FROM     cp 
        group by gid, geom --cp being the same point layer
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT   gid, 
                 geom 
        FROM     cp        -- cp being the same point layer
    )
    Select distinct geom as pts, 
           gid 
           , row_number() over () as id
    from   buffer
)
select * 
from b
left outer join a on b.gid = a.gid and b.id = a.id
;
```

Comment: Well, initially it returned 156 rows. Then, I slightly tweaked your code a bit. I added two lines. First, 'row_number() over ()  as id' in ALIAS 'b' and 'left outer join a on b.gid = a.gid and b.id = a.id' at the end of code and I got 13 rows. I would still give credit to you for initiating the solution. You may add these lines in your code.

Comment: Yes, I did! Thank you.

Comment: sorry - I meant - did I get your idea right :) did I update the answer as you meant? :)